# After Kubuntu Installation I just get a logo screen

Tags: linux, installation, kubuntu

I have run into this error. After a new install of Kubuntu from a Kubuntu bootable drive I just get a Kubuntu Logo. I am using a tower with mid to low tier hardware but I don't think that's the issue. Attached is a video that shows start up process.(skip is about 30 seconds of black screen) Any help would be appreciated if you have any questions I'll try to answer them.

Version: Kubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Video link: https://photos.app.goo.gl/NFVUG44fnDmYd8Xi6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. Try to access the recovery system (Hit ESC once as the "BIOS" text appears) or boot the install media in "Try" mode. 2. Either way you should be able to look in the text provided by `dmesg` and in the `/var/log/*` files.... this should(!) provide some more detail on where it all stops, fails or whatever...